# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:src' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha')

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-drawable, android-menu, android-7.0-nougat

I'm updating my project to **API level 25** (Android 7.1.1).

I've updated the `build.gradle` file:

- gradle plugin version
- support library versions
- `targetSdkVersion`
- `compileSdkVersion`

When I sync the project, I get the following error:

> **Error:(2752, 34)** No resource found that matches the given name (at ***`android:src`*** with value `@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha`).

The error mentions the root of the problem as ***`android:src`***.

The `abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha` is not used in my project. Perhaps it is being used in some library ... ??

What is the meaning of this, and how do I resolve this issue?

Does this require updating some other components such as the build tools or the Google repository?

I'm using `Android Studio 2.3.2` and `Gradle 3.3` if that helps.

Comment: Have you checked if any of your dependencies are using that resource?

Comment: @akash93: Exactly. Apart from the support libraries, I'm using the facebook SDK and the simplecropview library. I suspect that one of these two uses `@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha`.

Comment: You can search for abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha in whole project, If you find the location it is used, you can edit this resource(renaming with abc_ic_menu_overflow_material if available).

Answer (score 1):

This resource has renamed. Change this

`abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha`

TO

`abc_ic_menu_overflow_material` Solve the issue.

Comment: The origin point of the error is ***`'android:src'`***, not my project.

Comment: Can you add the link that shows all such renamed resources?